# Exclude particular folder items when published

Tags: sitecore-client, publishing

I am working on `Sitecore 9 update 2`, I have one folder named `Feature` and its child folders are `Picture, Videos, PDF Files, etc`.

When I am publishing 'Feature' folder from Ribbon bar Publish option, it publishes all child folders and its sub-items (Pictures, video, etc) to Web Database.

I don't want to publish any one of the child folder and its sub-items for example Videos folder and its items (video-1, video-2, etc). Are there any options available in the Sitecore user interface to exclude it?

I have tried with `Never Publish checkbox` and `Unpublish date` option but its working for the same item not for child items.

Please find attached screenshot for details:

[image]

Here I am going to publish Feature folder and its all child items except highlighted folder (1) and its children's.

Comment: When you will select the Never publish checkbox for the highlighted folder, it will work for its child items as well. can you make sure after selecting Never publish, your item is unpublished from web database?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Sitecore Publish Exclusion module. It can be downloaded from [Sitecore Marketplace](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/S/Sitecore_Publish_Exclusions.aspx).

This module gives you the ability to configure items that needs to be excluded from publish. You could have this configured in Sitecore as shown below, or in an XML configuration file if you do not wish this to be configured through Sitecore. You can also provide additional capabilities to configure this for each publishing target and publish mode – for instance, you may want to exclude certain items only from the publishing target used by your live sites, but not from your staging target. Or you may want to exclude the items from being published for incremental publish, but not when you explicitly publish the item through smart publish or through the auto publish in a workflow.

More information at [Sitecore Publish Exclusion Guide](https://thesitecorezone.wordpress.com/2015/10/31/sitecore-publish-exclusions/)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to publish only current item but not sub-items just uncheck checkbox `Publish subitems`.

[image]

If you want to publish only one folder with sub items then you need to check "Never Publish" checkbox for other folders and again need to publish parent folder

Comment: My query is different. I want only one particular folder(including child items) to never get publish but other subfolder(including child) should be publish.

Comment: @varun you can't publish items that sit underneath a folder that is not being published. You can't break the tree.